# Difference between data-toggle="tooltip" and data-tooltip="tooltip" in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

May anyone explain me what is the difference between `data-toggle="tooltip"` and `data-tooltip="tooltip"` in `bootstrap`?. Are they all used for making the tooltip?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use data-toogle="tooltip" for making the tooltip or data-toogle="popover" for making popover.

example :

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!">Hover over me</a>
```

or you can see on bootstrap documentation itself,
if you were using [bootstrap 2.3.2 tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips)
or the [latest bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)